# Erlang Dropbox Api

Tags: erlang, dropbox-api

I am using https://github.com/StepanKuzmin/erlang-dropbox to connect with dropbox api. I can use it from command line. But when I am trying to write all of this into a module and run it I am always getting an authorization error (403).

Here is part of my code:

```
crypto:start(),
ssl:start(),
inets:start(),
Key = "key",
Secret = "secret key",
[{"oauth_token_secret", TokenSecret}, {"oauth_token", Token}] = dropbox:request_token(Key, Secret),
io:format(Token),
Url = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" ++ Token,
httpc:request(post, {Url, [],"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", []},[],[]).
```

I am receiving the token but not being able to authorize it from code. I have tried to token data separately but did not work out.

Thanks
Samiul Monir

Comment: Are you using httpc:request to POST to the /authorize URL? That's actually a web page where you need to send the user in their browser to authorize the app, and not an API endpoint that you should programmatically connect to.

Comment: okay, that what I was thinking. So I have to manually authorize that from browser? is there any way that I can authorize using api ?

Comment: Yes, the user has to manually authorize your app, but only once. After that, the app can store and re-use the resulting access token.